# Are these two statements about Ramseyfication true?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-language, structuralism

They just seem *intuitively likely*, though I'm not feeling very au fait with what exactly Ramsey sentences are.

1. The Ramseyfication of everything that is necessarily true in a linguistic system leaves it unchanged.
2. A Ramseyfied theory can only have one unobservable referent (as its individual variables do not refer, but unobservable reality is referred to).

Comment: Maybe you should look up Ramsey sentences on Wikipedia to refresh your memory and then clarify the question.  For example, what do you mean by "they are only about what can only occur once"?  Do  you think a Ramsey sentence must describe a single event?

Comment: @ColinMcLarty from memory, the bound variables don't refer

Comment: @ColinMcLarty and, from memory, ramseyfication does away with (unobservable)  terms which re-occur. also, 1 seems the case if every a priori is analytic.
!!!!

Comment: misremembered, oh well !

Comment: @ColinMcLarty i'm not in a position to answer this at all, any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

OK so I completely forgot what [Ramsey sentences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey_sentence) are.

On point 2, supposing that every a priori proposition is analytic, then it seems each only needs one term replacing

> [Let's say](http://www.jimpryor.net/teaching/courses/mind/notes/ramseylewis.html) we want to explain what the different parts of a car are...
>   First, we transform our Car Theory into an existentially quantified
>   sentence, quantifying out all the bold terms our audience doesn't yet
>   understand.
>
> x1 x2 (...and x1 mixes gasoline and air and sends the mixture to x2,
>   which in turn...and that makes the wheels turn.)
>
> This is called the
>   Ramsey Sentence for our Car Theory (after the philosopher and
>   mathematician Frank Ramsey). Next we can define what it is to be a
>   carburetor and an ignition chamber as follows:
>
> A carburetor = an x1 such that   x2 (...and x1 mixes gasoline and air
>   and sends the mixture to x2, which in turn...and that makes the wheels
>   turn.)

right?

So supposing that the *sum* of analytic facts do not add up to anything which cannot be expressed in an analytic proposition, their sum only expresses something non-relational, like:

- every x is an unmarried man.

I think the sentence is non-relational because all analytic propositions tell us is a definition: of a term which is now eliminated.